# Format number to 2 decimal places

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, javascript, jquery

I have created a custom product field which is an auto-calculated field, which is saved to the meta data upon save.
The calculation of the field is carried out live using javascript/jQuery.
However, the calculation is not formating the figure to 2 decimal places:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
            function compute() {
                var a = jQuery('#_regular_price').val();
                var b = jQuery('#_weight').val();
                var total = a / b;
                var totalformatted = total.toFixed(2);
                jQuery('#shop_price_per_kg').val(totalformatted);
            }
            jQuery('#_regular_price, #_weight').change(compute);
        });
```

What am I doing wrong in my code for why this is not working?

Comment: The code looks fine, works for me. What do you expect to happen here? if you console.log() totalformatted does it look different there?

Comment: Note that this isn't specifically a Wordpress question, it's javascript and maybe jQuery which is offtopic for this stackexchange, and may be better posted in e.g. stackoverflow. A moderator may close it as off topic or they may leave it, just letting you know for future reference as it can be frustrating to have your posts closed even though they are related to Wordpress for you.